# Redux hooks problem while sending request to the backend

Tags: reactjs, spring, redux

First of all I am newbie at redux. I'm trying to create e-commerce website. At the back end side I'm handling login in the below code with spring.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> authenticate(
            @RequestBody LoginRequest request
    ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.authenticate(request));
    }
```

```
public AuthResponse authenticate(LoginRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        var user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
```

When a user logs in, I can access their email through JWT.
However, my challenge begins here. Upon logging in, I only have the user's email in React, and I need to retrieve the user's data using this email.
In React, I am attempting to send the logged user's email to the backend to access their data, but I am having an error related to frontend mistakes.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
```

My react-redux codes which is related with the error,

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            const userData = await login({ email: formikSignIn.values.signEmail , password: formikSignIn.values.signPassword }).unwrap();
            const data = await useGetLoggedUserQuery(formikSignIn.values.signEmail);
            console.log(data);
            dispatch(setCredentials({ ...userData, email: formikSignIn.values.signEmail }));
            setIsModalLoggedInOpen(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
                navigate('/home');
            }, 2000);
        } catch (err: any) {
            console.log(err.status);
            if (err.status === "FETCH_ERROR") {
                showErrorModal("No server response!", "Server is under maintenance, please try again later.");
            } else {
                if (err.status === 403) {
                    showErrorModal("Wrong email or password", "Please check your login informations again.");
                } else {
                    showErrorModal("Login failed!", "Please try again.");
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
export type UserState = {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    address?: string;
    role: Role;
  };

export type AuthState = {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user?: UserState; 
    token?: string;
};
  

enum Role {
    ADMIN = "ADMIN",
    USER = "USER",
}
```

```
export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        login: builder.mutation({
            query: credentials => ({
                url: '/auth/login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: { ...credentials }
            })
        }),
        getLoggedUser: builder.query({
            query: userEmail => `/user/${userEmail}`,  
        }),
    })
})

export const {
    useLoginMutation,
    useGetLoggedUserQuery 
} = authApiSlice
```

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authReducer
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
    devTools: true
})
```

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credentials: 'include',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const state = getState() as AuthState;
        const token = state.token;
        if (token) {
            headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
        }
        return headers;
    }
})

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args: any, api: any, extraOptions: any) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

    if (result?.error && 'originalStatus' in result.error){
        if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
            console.log('sending refresh token');
            const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh', api, extraOptions);
            console.log(refreshResult);
            if (refreshResult?.data) {
                const user = api.getState().user;
                api.dispatch(setCredentials({ ...refreshResult.data, user }));
                result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
            } else {
                api.dispatch(logOut({}));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```

Also, shouldn't using React with Redux result in less code in React components? Where am I making a mistake by writing too much codes in the functions for backend communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `useGetLoggedUserQuery` hook in the `handleSubmit` callback breaks  React's [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> ## Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

I suggest you export and use the [Lazy Query Hook](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) that returns a trigger function that can be used in your callback.

Example:

```js
export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    ....
    getLoggedUser: builder.query({
      query: userEmail => `/user/${userEmail}`,  
    }),
  })
})

export const {
  useLoginMutation,
  useGetLoggedUserQuery,
  useLazyGetLoggedUserQuery, // <-- lazy query hook
} = authApiSlice
```

```js
import { useLazyGetLoggedUserQuery } from '../path/to/apiSlice';

...

const [getLoggedUser] = useLazyGetLoggedUserQuery();

...

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const userData = await login({
      email: formikSignIn.values.signEmail,
      password: formikSignIn.values.signPassword
    }).unwrap();

    const data = await getLoggedUser(formikSignIn.values.signEmail).unwrap();

    console.log(data);
    dispatch(setCredentials({
      ...userData,
      email: formikSignIn.values.signEmail
    }));
    setIsModalLoggedInOpen(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate('/home');
    }, 2000);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err.status);
    if (err.status === "FETCH_ERROR") {
      showErrorModal(
        "No server response!",
        "Server is under maintenance, please try again later."
      );
    } else {
      if (err.status === 403) {
        showErrorModal(
          "Wrong email or password",
          "Please check your login informations again."
        );
      } else {
        showErrorModal("Login failed!", "Please try again.");
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
};
```